# About Threading of Binary Trees

Tags: c, data-structures

Is my understanding correct?

```
    A
   / \
  B   C
 / \
D   E
```

Just like this tree, when threading the preorder, if A is also threaded, its lchild should be NULL, and rchild should be D (ABDEC)
But the real threading does not require this, so in the actual code, the lchild and rchild of A are still B and C, is my understanding correct?

this is my code

```
void in_thread(struct node* root, struct node** parent) {
    if (root != NULL) {
        //left
        in_thread(root->l_child, parent);
        //deeling
        if (root->l_child == NULL) {
            root->ltag = 1;
            root->l_child = (*parent);
        }
        if ((*parent) != NULL && (*parent)->r_child == NULL) {
            (*parent)->rtag = 1;
            (*parent)->r_child = root;
        }
        (*parent) = root;
        //right
        in_thread(root->r_child, parent);
    }
}
```

Comment: Could you [edit] and reword the question? You're using the word "threading" which doesn't look right in this context and I don't really understand what you're asking. Maybe use translate.google.com to translate from your language into English.

Comment: i mean Threaded Binary Tree

Comment: @Jabberwocky: [Threaded binary tree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Threaded_binary_tree).